# Referencing a control from within a module

Tags: manipulate, scoping

Below is a simple Manipulate that references a module via a button, which resets a slider and value.

I would like to reference and reset the slider control for the 
slider "n" from within the module "half"
   Is there a way of referencing controls and passing them to modules?
   Is there a way of globally referencing a control?

````
half[v_] := Module[{output}, 
   output = v/2;
   (* 
   I would like to reference and reset the slider control for the \
slider "n" from within this module 
   Is there a way of referencing controls and passing them to modules?
   Is there a way of globally referencing a control?
Perhaps something like
Control["n"] = v;
   *)
    Print[output]; 
   output
   ];



Manipulate[
 n, {{n, 10, "n"}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 Button["half n", n = N[ half[n]]]
 ]
```
````

Comment: Is there something you would like to do that your code doesn't already do? If you click the "half n" button, the slider value changes correctly. Having a generic `half` function and then the assignment explicit in the `Button` seems like good coding standard to me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
 I don't want to make the example more complex as it will be harder to see the issue
 The code provided does work but the issue is setting the slider INSIDE the module
 As a button can do more or less one thing  I can wrap modules
 in modules to achieve multiple results, but I do not want the final result to be the slider action
  so I am trying to find how to access the slider control within the module
   one way would be to pass the slider object to the module but I can not see how to do that

Comment: A button could do many things -- just use `code; n = half[n]; more code` as the second argument. I don't think your code encapsulation will be the best if you go down this route... however, if you really want to do this, you don't need to worry about the slider at all, just the variable that the slider deals with. You could look into `HoldFirst` and other attributes. WL isn't object-oriented and there aren't references to objects that you can use.